# Video.js blackscreen only audio plays if height is over 225px

Tags: javascript, html, css, video-streaming, video.js

Im trying to play a video in video.js but when I set the height anywhere below 225px it shows a black screen and just the video audio plays. If you put the height to 225px or above it works correctly. The problem is my div I want the player in is smaller than 225px. Does anyone know what the problem is? Here is the code im using

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.js"></script>

<link href="https://unpkg.com/video.js/dist/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/video.js/dist/video.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/videojs-contrib-hls/dist/videojs-contrib-hls.js"></script>

<video id="example-video" class="video-js vjs-default-skin"  controls preload="auto" height="225" width="auto">
<source src="https://video-dev.github.io/streams/x36xhzz/x36xhzz.m3u8" type="application/x-mpegURL">
</video>

<script>
var player = videojs('example-video');   
player.play();   
</script>
```

Comment: It works in snippet so it would be probably some issue on your side and not in code you show. Btw. you are using hls plugin, but its already included in your videojs.

Answer (score 0):

place it inside a `<div>` with smaller height, then set the CSS `overflow` property to `hidden;`

Comment: but that just hides parts of the video, it doesnt resize it

Comment: you will adjust the `<video>` size, for the actual video, and you will adjust the `<div>` size for the viewport.